# How to show a image background when button is scelected or clicked

Tags: iphone

i have this code in the button click to show selection image when the button is clicked

```
 UIImage *img1 = [UIImage  imageNamed:@"settingpress.png"];

             [_btnclick setImage:img1 forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted+UIControlStateSelected)];

             [img1 release];
```

but i didn't get the image ,my button is a UIButton in xib with custom button not the Roundrect.what is the error in my code.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a button with style Custom (instead of RoundRect). Also, use the method: *-setBackgroundImage:forState:*

Comment: first check if the image name is correct and try displaying it in an imageview.if it works check with this code [_btnclick setBackgroundImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use background Image and the | separator:

```
[_btnclick setBAckgroundImage:img1 forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected)];
```